# How to properly add animation.css per result?

Tags: html, css

Hi I added this class to animate the result:

```
class="animated bounceInUp" // https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/
```

But how to animate result 1 by 1?
like 1st result then 2nd result with 0.4 delay per result.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the transition-delay property in the transition shorthand to do multiple transitions in sequence in one CSS rule.

```
-webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s ease 2s;
transition: width 2s, height 2s ease 2s;
```

Comment: I mean if the query find 4 result. it will display 1 by 1 with interval